# Attribute on root element in a JAX-WS service

Tags: java, xml, jaxb, jax-ws

I'm trying to annotate a java class which will in the input param in an JAX-WS based web service.

The following is the input class

```
@XmlRootElement
class InputClass
   @XmlAttribute
   private String type;
   @XmlElement
   private String id;
```

and the service operation signature:

```
@WebResult(name = "success")
public boolean operation(@WebParam(name = "input") InputClass input);
```

This gives input xml that look like this:

```
<input>
   <id type="something">an_id</id>
</input>
```

Is there any way to map the InputClass so that it produces XML that look like this:

```
<id type="something">an_id</id>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @XmlValue for this:

```
@XmlRootElement(name="id")
class InputClass
   @XmlAttribute
   private String type;
   @XmlValue
   private String id;
}
```